# People.Connections.List nextSyncToken expires after one week

Tags: google-people-api

I am working on an contact sync solution to be able to keep the contacts in our app in sync with the google contacts of the user.

Our code uses the php library for the google people api latest Version (v1).

Everything is working fine for one week with each user but after that week we get:

> 400 - Error "Sync token is expired. 
>   Clear local cache and retry call without the sync token".

My question now:

**Is this intended behaviour that you have to clear all your cache after one week with no changes or am I doing something wrong?**

**Is there any possibility to renew a syncToken if there were no changes?**

I already checked the whole code to be sure that the new received `nextSyncToken` is saved at our side and used for the next incremental sync request. It seems that the new sync Token is always the same as the one sent in the request. Thus it is just clear that we get that errors if a sync token expires after exactly one week.
I also tried to set the option `requestSyncToken` to `true` for every list request, even if also a `syncToken` is set. No success. Sync token stays the same after each request with no changes.

Comment: Hi, could you please share a sample piece of your code without any senstive data showing the part where you are using the tokens? Also, have you checked out the difference between ```requestSyncToken``` and ```SyncToken``` ? Also, could you please verify with me that the [initial set up](https://developers.google.com/people/v1/getting-started#3.-set-up-your-app) to the API is properly done and it does not interfer the token variables witht the sync token ones? Cheers!

Comment: Thank you for posting an answer! But after 8 months it is possible that Google already fixed that or changed some behaviour in their API so maybe the problem is no longer a problem. We found a solution 8 months ago but even though your answer would not have been any helpful. I told the whole process and API is working fine, also calendar sync, so the initial set up or wrong SyncTokens or some interference can simply not be a problem. And yes - we did all the stuff but we still needed to refresh the whole synchronization once a week if no new SyncToken was received because of some changes made.

Comment: I see. So your workaround solved your issue? In that case, could you formalise the above explanation into an answer to this question so that other users with similar issues can see the workaround easily? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case someone is also facing this problem (`syncToken` expiration after one week without changes in the persons/contacts list):

Our solution was:

- Save the creation date and time of a new `syncToken` each time you
  get one together with the `syncToken`.
- When you receive a `syncToken` in an incremental sync process compare that token to the stored one. If the `syncToken` is a new
  one, overwrite the old one and its creation date/time.
- Use a continuous process that checks each `syncToken`. If one is about one week old (for security reasons we used 6 days) create a new
  `syncToken` (process see below). As the people API does not offer
  things like the watch-channels of the calendar API you would anyway
  need some continuous processes that do list-calls in fixed time
  intervals for a complete real-time synchronization - so maybe you
  could combine these tasks depending on your solution for this
  problem?!

Process for creation of a new SyncToken:

- Do a new list request without providing a `syncToken`.
- For additional security do some checkups like compare the total persons received with the total persons expected by the old/current
  data. And do this renew process at a time of the day when almost no
  one does changes generally, for example like 2am.
- Overwrite the old `syncToken` and date/time with the new one and the current date/time.

That's it.

But attention! You can still miss some changes that were made if your `syncToken` renew process is running exactly at the time a change is made!

Answer (score 0):

Create a dummy contact before the sync to get a new `syncToken`. After the sync delete the dummy contact from both Google Contacts and your cache.

Comment: Does this really work? sync token is already expired and I doubt it will be revived after contact is created.

Comment: @Bonias Ah I see that I left out an important detail, sorry about that, let me clarify: You won't get a new sync token if no changes were made, which leads to the latest sync token becoming 1 week old and expiring, so my idea was to make changes regularly to ensure the renewal of the sync token (so the next request with `syncToken` will return a new token) and avoid risking the possibility that a change will be missed between the expiration of the old token and the creation of a new token. But I didn't test it myself, because I don't need to worry about the slowness of sync without token.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. This should work indeed, although it doesn't seem to be a "clean" solution.